# Symfony templating array doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I use Symfony. I created Helper Class SendMessage

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;

class SendMessage
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(Container $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function addEntityMessage($creator, $projectName, $type, $sendTo)
    {
        $mailer = $this->container->get('mailer');
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Hello Email')
            ->setFrom('emailFrom@gmail.com')
            ->setTo($sendTo)
            ->setBody(
                $this->container->get('templating')
                    ->render('MyBundle:Email:new_entity.html.twig'), array(
                    'creator' => $creator,
                    'name' => $projectName,
                    'type' => $type
                )
            )
        ;
        $mailer->send($message);
    }
}
```

My Tempalte  is new_entity.html.twig

```
{{ creator }} created new  {{ type }}. {{type }} name is {{ name }}
```

But don't work. Error message.

```
Variable "creator" does not exist in MyBundle::Email:new_entity.html.twig at line 1
```

How to solve this problem. Any one help me. Sorry my english not very well.

Answer (score 3):

You don't sending parameters to twig (render function), there is fix:

```
$this->container->get('templating')
                    ->render('MyBundle:Email:new_entity.html.twig', array(
                    'creator' => $creator,
                    'name' => $projectName,
                    'type' => $type
                ))
```

Comment: How can I send parameters to twig in heper class?

Comment: @Akim Use mi fix. In your code you are sending parameters to setBody function and you must send it to get('templating')
                    ->render() functiion